# Version of std::stoi rejecting any non-number

Tags: c++

As you may know, `std::sto*` function family works in a way that reads number in string until it finds non-number, like that:

```
std::string pseudoNum = "123haha";
int num = std::stoi(pseudoNum); //no problem, num = 123
```

Is there any standard way to have more strict integer parsing, which causes exception/error code return in such situations (when string is not completely integer)?

Comment: I don't think there's a standard one. I usually write my own functions for that on top of `std::strtol`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat if you could give it answer it would stil be a good one :)

Comment: You can of course check if `std::string(num)==pseudoNum` but that fails on `"0123"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use C++17's [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) and check the length of the parsed value:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <charconv>

int main() {
    const std::string str { "123haha" };
    int value = 0;
    const auto result = std::from_chars(str.data(), 
                                        str.data() + str.size(), 
                                        value);

    if (result.ec == std::errc()) {
        std::cout << "Value: " << value << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Length: " << result.ptr - str.data() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMS4B2UgAdUCwuto9QxNBHz81Ohs7RyMXN05FZUxVAIYCZmICIONTcyUVCNo0jIIoh2dXD0V0zOyQhIUa0tty2MrOAEpFVANiZA4AcikAZltkQywAanFhnXVG4kxmIxnscQAGAEERsYnMadnkBAy0WgA3VY3trdsCSaNmWwgO6fdZLcnPydPGycb0EAgBa2YB/AjEV7SaaSSScSTDY7HKSSV4AERm702X0mt0mZzYBn2M1Rk3WGKu2J%2Bd2YBiIk0WCgMrDuxLBAJAVGIqCMAH0jhkFBAFgA6dDMdLPUjTD7Y2Vy%2BUKxUisUSl5yMHEYV%2BABemEl0qxiqNxsV%2BMMmA65K2FK%2BeCokwgDKZBGFyQO6OGJP%2BgNcfWeareNrl3pQPRZsxmOmhkgAagSONGDjpI3j40mUyHLKwrYbgwR2WhaenZtGrFpgAQkInIymnczhV5wZMALQa0Xi5jPYtRzPabPDTHY8TudHWmWfRYEXq0Uk54eogZdVggAYAVgGpFMA3WG9QK%2BTMnVCh6fSJ8M4G4IK53HS6AGsQNwAJzC4bcdySVcADm4X9XADZhiff8nyEFduA3Lcd1IPcBg3BQQHWUgr23RdSDgWAYEQUMjC8PB2DICgIDQXD8MqYAn3MKh8IIVwEIgJxrw3JxbAyABPFcL1IEijC0AgAHlaFYDjUNILAHlEdgmLEvBFhSM5MAQ0TMAAD2SWlBmg25lGk1g8CcYh2L0LBOMvYg8CMUyuhoegmDYDgeH4QRhFEFA5DkIR9IQyAulQRsAiU5t/mJCRDxkTh3HgpIUg0CBLDqUwEksMoYjiUJfH8OgEvS8IAhSip4kSApUiabKGmiwpikyfK2kKxoSjK6oShqtLOm6Xp%2Bi4JcV3XTdpNglSv3/Zt/24SZgGQZBJhfFEIFwQgSGhYYEkmPRSIIpbOlW9yZEvJjb1IB9V2GYV3G4SQv2A4ZhlXX9LuGMCBgg0hLNXJCoN3Fd4MQ5D9vQrCICQMMvFpchKBIvCCMETB8CIQqbMYFgpMcgB3QyvCsx7eo%2BmCVxGThJhRwgEEmQbhtG8bJum4VJD21CDoQJYsDcSVlyejdXve/qvsUH6UJve8QDe4V/1XSQzs4VceGGf91mWx7hkg7m4N%2B%2BnuoGWm%2BtE2C6YF0gFOIPwNG4IA%3D)

**C++11 solution**

A second parameter to `std::stoi` is an address of an integer to store the number of characters processed.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const std::string str { "123haha" };
    std::size_t processed_chars = 0;
    int value = std::stoi(str, &processed_chars);

    std::cout << "Value: " << value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Length: " << processed_chars << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++const+std::string+str+%7B+%22123haha%22+%7D%3B%0A++++std::size_t+processed_chars+%3D+0%3B%0A++++int+value+%3D+std::stoi(str,+%26processed_chars)%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22Value:+%22+%3C%3C+value+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22Length:+%22+%3C%3C+processed_chars+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:49.34725848563969,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:53.74289633548893,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50.65274151436031,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Comment: as much as I like this answer, I don't have C++17 yet :(

Comment: @bartop I will try to write a C++11 part of the answer too

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the second argument suite you?
Second argument of std::stoi is very usefull for that: if returned position is equills the size of the string then whole string is a number.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of `std::sto*()` methods is `std::size_t * pos` which will be set to the number of numeric characters used for the conversion (can be seen [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)).

This is how I implemented this:

```
int my_stoi(const std::string & str)
{
    std::string::size_type pos;
    const int value = std::stoi(str, /* out */ &pos);

    if (pos != str.size())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed parsing string '" << str << "' as an integer" << std::endl;
    }

    return value;
}
```